# Completing the square to find the Fourier transform of a Gaussian

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fourier-transform

I'm trying to find the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian, and I end up having to complete the square in the argument of an exponential so I can use the standard Gaussian integral. I basically have:

$$\bar f(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}-ikx}dx$$

And I have trouble finding the polynomial I need. I end up doing something like:

We require a function of the form $(\frac{x-c}{a} + A)^2$ such that

$$-2c+2Aa = ikx$$

as I believe  $(\frac{x-c}{a} + A)^2 = (x + (-c + Aa))^2$ should be equivalent?

$$\implies A = \frac{ikx + 2c}{2a}$$

However, this doesn't solve the problem. I need $A$ to not be a function of $x$. How should I instead approach this?

Comment: Your belief is heresy.  What is ((x - c) /a + A)$^2$?

Comment: @WilliamElliot In order to make a $u^2$ substitution, I need the argument of the exponential in that form, but I don’t know what $A$ is yet.

Comment: It appears you skipped some steps in your algebra resulting in error.